# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' in JBoss Fuse

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi, jbossfuse

I develop a bundle under JBoss Fuse which persists some data into DB. My DAO failes to initialize connection pool to the Oracle DB due to exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load
>   JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>
> at
>   bank.dao.CorrelationInfoDaoImpl.insertCorellationInfo(CorrelationInfoDaoImpl.java:25)
>
> ... 28 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found by io.fabric8.fabric-jolokia
>   [98]

Neither 
`<DynamicImport-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</DynamicImport-Package>`
, nor artifact `wrap:mvn:com.oracle.jdbc/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2` inclusion, nor bean declaration at Blueprint descriptor 
`<bean id="dictDS-driver-class-name" class="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>` does not help. Could anyone give an idea, how to solve it?

Here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bank</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdpFMOutConcurrent</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven-bundle-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <camel-maven-plugin-version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</camel-maven-plugin-version>
        <fabric8-maven-plugin-version>1.2.0.redhat-621084</fabric8-maven-plugin-version>
        <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.2.1.redhat-084</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
        <datamodel.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</datamodel.version>
        <ojdbc7.version>12.1.0.2</ojdbc7.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>   

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Custom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bank</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataModel</artifactId>
            <version>${datamodel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The ActiveMQ client with connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc7.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Private-Package>bank.*</Private-Package>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</DynamicImport-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${fabric8-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-xsd-files</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>bank</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>DataModel</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>bundle</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <includes>
                                ASBOFMOut/*.xsd,
                                GBOCommon/*.xsd,
                                ASBOFMDataModel/*.xsd
                            </includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/resources/model</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JAXB xjc plugin that invokes the xjc compiler to compile XML schema into Java classes.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- The schema directory or xsd files. -->
                    <sources>
                        <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/resources/model</source>
                    </sources>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxbBinding.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <xjcSourceExcludeFilters>
                        <filter implementation="org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.filters.pattern.PatternFileFilter">
                            <patterns>
                                <pattern>\.svn.*</pattern>
                            </patterns>
                        </filter>
                    </xjcSourceExcludeFilters>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is Blueprint descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd          http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder id="adpfmoutconcurrent" persistent-id="adpfmoutconcurrent">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="broker.url" value="discovery:(fabric:public)"/>
            <cm:property name="broker.username" value="admin"/>
            <cm:property name="broker.password" value="admin"/>

            <cm:property name="max.connections" value="5"/>
            <cm:property name="concurrent.consumers" value="10"/>
            <cm:property name="max.concurrent.consumers" value="15"/>

            <cm:property name="persistence.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <cm:property name="persistence.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.3.42:1521:ESBDB"/>
            <cm:property name="persistence.username" value="esb_db_dev3"/>
            <cm:property name="persistence.password" value="esb_db_dev3"/>
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${broker.url}"/>
        <property name="userName" value="${broker.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${broker.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="${max.connections}"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsCamelConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${concurrent.consumers}"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="${max.concurrent.consumers}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="publicamq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsCamelConfig"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${persistence.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${persistence.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${persistence.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${persistence.password}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="correlationInfoDao" class="bank.dao.CorrelationInfoDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="correlationInfoPersister" class="bank.processor.CorrelationInfoPersister">
        <property name="correlationInfoDao" ref="correlationInfoDao"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="adpfmoutconcurrent-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <package>bank.route</package>
        <dataFormats>
            <jaxb id="asbofmout" prettyPrint="true" contextPath="bank.asbofmout"/>
        </dataFormats>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`<DynamicImport-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver</DynamicImport-Package>`
Use package name but not the classname

Btw, more explanation about this kind of issue is described [here](http://freemanfang.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-use-jdbc-driver-in-osgi.html)

Comment: Thank you for response! I have corrected DynamicImport-Package block, but it have had no effect, despite of having wrapped ojdbc driver (added to Fabric profile). In the end, I could not figure out the reason of the problem. I ended up by using Spring SimpleDriverDataSource instead of Apache BasicDataSource. SimpleDriverDataSource does not call Class.forName(). But since SimpleDriverDataSource is not a connection pool the question is still open.